# Xcode memory leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm analyzed my code which uses a `WebViewController` and I am getting memory leaks.

Could this simple code really be causing such issues?

```
- (IBAction) google: (id) sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Google"];
    [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
    //[webViewController release];
}
```

If I uncomment the release, then there is no leak, but after a few clicks through Google, it will crash the program. So I'm not sure if I should leave the leak in the program since at least then it works. Can anyone provide some insight? So after navigating thorugh pages in the webview and click the Done button it will go back to my main view for 1 second and crash.

Crash Output (Under WebThread)
http://pastebin.com/A8ELm18R

Comment: Can you post what it says in XCode when it crashed? What you have there isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to release the web view at a later time, after you are done using it. Keep track of it with a property and then when you dismiss the modal you can release it.

You could also use autorelease like such:

```
- (IBAction) google: (id) sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Google"] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Or take the easy (and not so efficient) way out.. autorelease! :P

Comment: True, this should work as well. I'm just anal about managing my memory :)

Comment: yeah i pretty much tried everything, is autorelease better than just leaving the memory leak there? Can you tell me how it is implemented

Comment: Autorelease would be better because it would fix the leak :) I'll edit my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: are there any cons to this way? Also the reason to find memory leaks is because the more the leaks there are, the more probability the app may crash?

Comment: The only con is that you don't know exactly when it is released. It could stay in memory longer than necessary, making the app slightly less memory-efficient, however this is almost never an issue since autorelease is designed to work well with the device's memory usage. The reason to find leaks is that if you have a leak, as the user performs the leaky action you use up memory and don't give it back, and eventually this will slow the phone down and crash the app.

Comment: alright thanks, hmm i replaced all with autorelease but yeah it seems like it crashes after i navigate 3-4 pages, and only after i click done it crashses to the springboard

Comment: Can you post the crash? It might be a different issue entirely. Please edit it into your original question.

Comment: i hope that's the crash you're talking about, this is my first app, and I think I'm doing pretty well, but these memory leaks are driving me crazy